# How would you express this in Haskell?

Tags: algorithm, haskell, if-statement

Would you use if/else to write this algorithm in Haskell? Is there a way to express it without them? It's hard to extract functions out of the middle that have meaning. This is just the output of a machine learning system.

I'm implementing the algorithm for classifying segments of html content as Content or Boilerplate described [here](https://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/wiki/WSDM2010Paper). This has the weights already hard coded.

```
curr_linkDensity <= 0.333333
| prev_linkDensity <= 0.555556
| | curr_numWords <= 16
| | | next_numWords <= 15
| | | | prev_numWords <= 4: BOILERPLATE
| | | | prev_numWords > 4: CONTENT
| | | next_numWords > 15: CONTENT
| | curr_numWords > 16: CONTENT
| prev_linkDensity > 0.555556
| | curr_numWords <= 40
| | | next_numWords <= 17: BOILERPLATE
| | | next_numWords > 17: CONTENT
| | curr_numWords > 40: CONTENT
curr_linkDensity > 0.333333: BOILERPLATE
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there are just three paths in this decision tree that leads to a BOILERPLATE state, I'd just iterate and simplify them:

```
isBoilerplate =
  prev_linkDensity   <= 0.555556 && curr_numWords <= 16 && prev_numWords <= 4
  || prev_linkDensity > 0.555556 && curr_numWords <= 40 && next_numWords <= 17
  || curr_linkDensity > 0.333333
```

Comment: I think you want `or`, not `any`. Also you could use `||` instead, or use `and` instead of the `&&`s.

Answer (score 11):

Not simplifying the logic manually (assuming you might generate this code automatically), I think using [`MultiWayIf`](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/guide-to-ghc-extensions/basic-syntax-extensions#multiwayif) is pretty clean and direct.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiWayIf #-}

data Stats = Stats {
    curr_linkDensity :: Double,
    prev_linkDensity :: Double,
    ...
}

data Classification = Content | Boilerplate

classify :: Stats -> Classification
classify s = if
    | curr_linkDensity s <= 0.333333 -> if
      | prev_linkDensity s <= 0.555556 -> if
        | curr_numWords s <= 16 -> if
          | next_numWords s <= 15 -> if
            | prev_numWords s <= 4 -> Boilerplate
            | prev_numWords s > 4 -> Content
          | next_numWords s > 16 -> Content
      ...
```

and so on.

However, since this is so structured -- just a tree of if/else with comparisons, also consider creating a decision tree data structure and writing an interpreter for it.  This will allow you to do transformations, manipulations, inspections.  Maybe it will buy you something; defining miniature languages for your specifications can be surprisingly beneficial.

```
data DecisionTree i o 
    = Comparison (i -> Double) Double (DecisionTree i o) (DecisionTree i o)
    | Leaf o

runDecisionTree :: DecisionTree i o -> i -> o
runDecisionTree (Comparison f v ifLess ifGreater) i
    | f i <= v  = runDecisionTree ifLess i
    | otherwise = runDecisionTree ifGreater i
runDecisionTree (Leaf o) = o

-- DecisionTree is an encoding of a function, and you can write
-- Functor, Applicative, and Monad instances!
```

Then

```
 classifier :: DecisionTree Stats Classification
 classifier =
     Comparison curr_linkDensity 0.333333
       (Comparison prev_linkDensity 0.555556
         (Comparison curr_numWords 16
           (Comparison next_numWords 15
             (Comparison prev_numWords 4
               (Leaf Boilerplate)
               (Leaf Content))
             (Leaf Content)
           ...
```

Comment: For the first method, the `MultiWayIf` extension allows you to write that prettier, replacing `case () of _` by `if`.

Comment: Minor comment: I have a personal distaste for guards which are meant to cover all cases (i.e. be exhaustive) and do not use `otherwise` for the last guard. I use `otherwise` because I find it to express the intent better, I do not have to repeat the condition twice, and is more efficient that anything else. Also, when an inner `if` has non-exhaustive branches, it's very easy (for me, at least) to think that Haskell will backtrack to the next outer `if` branch. This is however not the case, and a non-exhaustive match runtime error arises. For these reasons I strongly prefer the last alternative

Comment: @chi As far as I can remember, GHC still lacks a proper syntax for nested branching patterns/guards which *do* backtrack, although I think it's been discussed before.